# what would happen for a init** method without return value in arc?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

In the arc naming convention says : the init*** method 's return value will be retained by caller, but if i wrote a init*** method without return value , Is it will cause some memory problem in ARC?

```
- (void)initToolbar
{
    // 工具栏
    UIButton *commendEditButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 0, [Utils getScreenAppSize].width - 15 *2, 32)];
    commendEditButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    commendEditButton.layer.borderColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xb6b6b6).CGColor;
    commendEditButton.layer.cornerRadius = 4.f;
    commendEditButton.layer.borderWidth = .5f;
    [commendEditButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showCommentCompose) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [commendEditButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"comment-ico-compose"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [commendEditButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"comment-ico-compose"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [commendEditButton setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];
    [commendEditButton setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0)];
    [commendEditButton setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 0, 0)];
    [commendEditButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f]];
    [commendEditButton setTitleColor:UIColorFromRGB(0xc4c4c4) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [commendEditButton setTitle:@"发表评论" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSArray *toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:commendEditButton],nil];
    _toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, [Utils getScreenSize].height - UI_TOOL_BAR_HEIGHT - UI_STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT - UI_NAVIGATION_BAR_HEIGHT, [Utils getScreenAppSize].width, UI_TOOL_BAR_HEIGHT)];
    [_toolBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"toolbar_bg.png"] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionBottom barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    _toolBar.items = toolbarItems;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing really bad will happen if you don't count violating many code quality rules.

```
@implementation A

- (void)initTest {
    // do nothing
}

@end


A *instance = [A alloc];
[instance initTest];
```

Note the instance is still strongly referenced, we didn't even call `[super init]`.

But we are very lucky here because `init` on `NSObject` does nothing.

In practice, this is very dependent on the superclass and in theory this is undefined behavior. The current implementation allows everything to work correctly but it's terrible code indeed.